# How to save data to sqlite3 database using Swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite

I want to save a particular set of data to my local sqlite3 db. Following here is my code and everything is working fine but the values are not getting populated in my table. Please guide me how to do that

```
func insertValues(){
        database?.open()
        let value = database?.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO cached_image (image_name,download_url) VALUES (?,?)", withArgumentsIn: ["back_stretch","back_stretch"])

        let value1 = database?.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO cached_image (image_name,download_url) VALUES (?,?)", withArgumentsIn: ["back_stretch1","back_stretch1"])

        print(value1)//The output is optional("true")
        print(value)//The output is optional("true")

        database?.close()

    }
```

Comment: You should follow a tutorial like https://www.raywenderlich.com/385-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @AllenR thanks for responding. I completed tutorial above and I am able to query the table, but the mentioned query statements are not working. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Are you using FMDB here?

Comment: @AllenR Yes I am using FMDB

Comment: The docs say to insert like so: `try db.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO authors (identifier, name, date, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", values: [identifier, name, date, comment ?? NSNull()])` You can try to change `withArgumentsIn` to `values`. If that doesn't work you should verify that your DB connection is actually open.

Comment: Till now I didn't added libsqlite3.dylib to xcode. Will it be the possible reason for this issue?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons it might not be working. That could be one of them. I don't really see anything wrong with the code you provided. The problem is probably else where.